# digitial signature amazon app store

Tags: android, amazon-appstore

I read like this in Amazon app store. What does this mean? Do i have to do some thing explicitily or Amazon themselves put a signature. I am not clear. Can you please tell me.

Can I apply a signature to my app?
All applications must be digitally signed with a certificate. The default signature applied to your app is a certificate supplied by Amazon that is unique to your developer account. If your signing strategy requires that a different certificate be applied, you may do so by submitting a request via the "Questions about application signatures" subject in the Contact Us section of the Amazon Appstore Developer Portal. Please indicate the title of the application for which you are submitting the request.

Answer (score 6):

You don't need to sign the apk for the Amazon Appstore. Just export an **unsigned** apk and submit that to Amazon. They will sign it with their own certificate.

If you wish, you **can** sign the apk with your own certificate before submitting to Amazon, but then they will end up signing it with theirs <strike>and you'll have an apk with two certificates</strike>. As you've already read, you can also request to have the apk signed only by your own certificate if you need the signatures to match for some reason.

### Update

I ended up emailing Appstore Dev support about this and here is their answer:

> In that case we would review your submission and decide if it requires
>   your signature. If we deem it does, we would enable the signature
>   feature and send you instructions, but if we deem it does not we would
>   override your signature with our own.

With this information I now simply submit the same APK that I signed and uploaded to Google Play; since Amazon will override that certificate anyway I don't bother compiling an unsigned APK at all.

Comment: @ Turbo are you sure that you'll end up with a double-signed APK? I have been trying to track the truth of this down, but I can't find authoritative information. (My resulting question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21100489/what-happens-when-an-apk-has-two-signatures-and-an-upgrade-with-one-signature-is )

Comment: @nmr Actually I ended up emailing help at the Amazon Appstore; **turns out they just override the original signature**. However, if you really need your own  signature you can request it. I've updated my answer.

Comment: I don't think you even need to request it, I found that self-signing was available directly via Amazon's dashboard.

Comment: @nmr you're probably right. I've never actually tried to use that feature.

Comment: Any to download amazon signed apk from app store.