# Using Google Drive API in Amazon causes 403 error

Tags: android, google-drive-api

My app is using Google Drive API to store and load files which are saved under the users' drive account. This works well for all the users who downloaded my app from Google Play however users who are using the same app which I uploaded to the Amazon app store are getting this error when trying to access their drive:

com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException:
403 Forbidden
{
 "code": 403,
   "errors": [
     {
       "domain":
"usageLimits",
       "message": "Access
Not Configured",
       "reason":
"accessNotConfigured"
     }
  ],
   "message": "Access Not Configured"
 }

Does the Amazon app store changes something in the APK that is causing an authentication error? If so, how can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Drive API uses two information to check which app you are.

1. Signing certificate fingerprint (SHA1)
2. Package name

These two information together should match the information you provided to APIs Console.
I guess this is an issue due to certificate fingerprint based on this [Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9713098/digitial-signature-amazon-app-store).